# Dynamic column in where clause

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to execute a query like this:

```
SELECT Id,Name,Distance=dbo.CalculateDistance(Lat,Lon,@lat,@lon)
FROM Requests
WHERE Distance < 2
ORDER BY Distance DESC
```

Error says,there is no Distance column.
I tried this once but it cuts off query performance

```
SELECT Id,Name,Distance=dbo.CalculateDistance(Lat,Lon,@lat,@lon)
FROM Requests
WHERE dbo.CalculateDistance(Lat,Lon,@lat,@lon) < 2
--ORDER BY Distance DESC
```

Without doing a second calculation,how can I achieve above query ?

Best Regards
Myra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the link below suggesting that you make a nested select and filter on its values; in this case the scalar computation will only be performed once.

So you should be able to do something like

```
        SELECT Id, Name, Distance FROM (
        SELECT Id,Name,Distance=dbo.CalculateDistance(Lat,Lon,@lat,@lon)
        FROM Requests) derived 
        WHERE Distance < 2 
        ORDER BY Distance DESC
```

I had a brief look at the execution plan, and the scalar computation only happens once. But you should certainly check the use of indices etc.

I hope it is om some help though.

[Avoid Transact-SQL's Column Alias Limitations](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/41095/1954)

Comment: Thank you faester,I tried and nested query goes into RAM and second which is first and executed only once :)